# Mysql 1366 error- utf8mb4 encoding used

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

```
def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='otrs',     user='root', password='password', autocommit=True)
    if conn.is_connected():
        print('connected')
    sqlstr = "SELECT ticket.id, article.id, ticket_history.create_time, article.a_body FROM ticket, ticket_history, article WHERE ticket_history.ticket_id=ticket.id AND ticket_history.article_id=article.id AND (ticket.ticket_state_id=2 OR ticket.ticket_state_id=3) AND ticket_history.name ='%%Close' ;"

    cursor.execute(sqlstr)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print row
        val= row[3].replace('\'','')
        print val
        sqlstr1 = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES (%s, %s, '%s','%s')" %(row[0], row[1], row[2], val)
        cursor.execute(sqlstr1)
        print 'done'
```

I wrote a python query to insert select data from tables in mysql table and write them to a temp table. When I execute the query, after few data rows are inserted, it raises an exceptions like

```
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8BWil...'
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8BVid...'
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8BSol...'
```

Entries which raise issues are,

```
(2932, 10503, datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 19, 17, 2, 7), u'Hi Arshadh,\n\nThis has been configured on PR FWSM device only\n\nBR,\n\u200bViduna\n\xa0')
(3136, 13353, datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 12, 40, 35), u'This has been postponed as we need support from forinet TAC team to resolve\nthis.\nWaiting for their feedback.\n\u200bWill raise new ticket when we get update from them\n')
(3661, 18395, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 27, 15, 34, 45), u'This request has been performed on 1/26/2017,\n\u200bSince the testing is getting delayed- closing the cr\xa0\nwe can reopen this again if there is any problem.\n')
```

But the below data set doesn't raise an error,

```
(3672, 18393, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 27, 15, 28, 9), u'This request has been performed on 1/26/2017,\nSince the testing is getting delayed- closing the cr\xa0\nwe can reopen this again if there is any problem.\n')
```

So it raises an issue if with there is \n\u200b instead of \n .
I searched everywhere, but couldn't find a solution. I think error is because of ASCII special characters. But I don't know how to solve the issue.

Comment: Why do you fetch the data to the client side? Use `insert ... select ...` syntax within MySQL to transfer data directly between tables.

Comment: I wanted to find the error which didn't allow me to run that query

Comment: `insert into temp_calc_resolved SELECT ticket.id, ticket_history.create_time, article.a_body FROM ticket,ticket_history, article WHERE ticket_history.ticket_id=ticket.id  and (ticket.ticket_state_id =2 OR ticket.ticket_state_id =3) and ticket_history.name ="%%Close" and ticket_history.article_id=article.id;`

Comment: Does this query work for you?

Comment: No, it raises the same error

Comment: Then you need to check the various encodings (table / field + connection)

Comment: Can you please explain it more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4
It was because MySQL’s utf8 charset only partially implements proper UTF-8 encoding. So converting database to utf8mb4 solved the issue.

## For each database:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

## For each table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Executing these queries, solved the issue.